# Number of tuples in a SQLite android intern database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, tuples

I'd like to know if there is a maximum number of tuples you can enter in an intern SQLite database for an Android app

And because the data is stored on the device, what is approximatively the number of tuples that is resonable not to exceed ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I guess this is a good reference: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Okay thanks that helped ! :)
Post an answer so I can vote up for it ;)